# How to get a list of data from firebase database?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get some list data and put in a list. But I couldn't make it. I tried so many things but none of them is worked.

This is my database structure.
[image: Database Structure]

So there is a main root which is user then username in this case it is "mm". This node includes some data and some other nodes. Expenses is one of them. In expenses there are some unique keys. Every unique key indicates a different receipt. And each unique key stores products of this receipt. In this case there are three ( 0-1-2). There is no limitation to three. It can be 3 or 1 or 15. Each of this nodes store a value in "Expenses" class type.

I want to take this datas into a list. So this list should store data like that.

```
{
    {
        Receipt1: {
            amount: 1,
            marketName: "aa",
            price: 2,
            productName: "bb"
        },
        {
            amount: 2,
            marketName: "cc",
            price: 3,
            productName: "dd"
        }
    }, {
        Receipt2: {
            {
                amount: 3,
                marketName: "ee",
                price: 5,
                productName: "ff"
            },
            {
                amount: 1,
                marketName: "gg",
                price: 7,
                productName: "jj"
            },
            {
                amount: 9,
                marketName: "nn",
                price: 5,
                productName: "vv"
            }
        }
    }
```

So I should able to access Receipts seperately. If I search for Receipt1 then I should get 3 nodes like example.

I try to get this datas like that. But It doesn't work.

```
private void receiptGetter(String userName,SimpleCallback<Boolean> finishedCallback) {

        DatabaseReference rootRef = databaseManager.getReference();
        DatabaseReference expensesRef = rootRef.child("user").child(userName).child("expenses");
        Query queryReceiptFinder = expensesRef.orderByKey();
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    expenses = ds.getValue(Expenses.class);
                    expensesList.add(expenses);

                }
                finishedCallback.run(true);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("error", databaseError.getMessage());
                finishedCallback.run(false);
            }
        };
        queryReceiptFinder.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }
```

Then I try to get this data like that.

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            receiptGetter("userName", (success) -> {
                if (success) {
                    String receipt = expensesList.toString();
                    receiptText.setText(receipt);
                } else
                    Log.d("error", getString(R.string.ErrorOccured));
            });
```

Comment: you can read snapshot as ArrayList of object in your case

Answer (score 0):

I think Firestore is more suitable for your purpose than realtime database. If you can use it in the documentation you can see how to access every document.

This is a link for the official documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

In general you can access a document with:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
// asynchronously retrieve the document
ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
// ...
// future.get() blocks on response
DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
if (document.exists()) {
  System.out.println("Document data: " + document.getData());
} else {
  System.out.println("No such document!");
}
```

if you have nested document:

```
db.collection("cities").document("SF").collection("nameCollection").document("documentName");
```

Comment: yes but this is a big project. I am working on it for a quite while. This method is just a implementation to current application. I can't swap it to firestore this will take so much time. But thank you for information I will use firestore for my future development purposes